# All elements inside a div on a single line

Tags: css, html

What I want to accomplish is keep all elements inside a div on a single line no matter how many there are:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 items">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="image pull-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="images/product.png">
        </div>

        <div class="text pull-left">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
            <p>$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
            <h6 class="blue">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="image pull-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="images/product.png">
        </div>

        <div class="text pull-left">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
            <p>$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
            <h6 class="blue">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="image pull-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="images/product.png">
        </div>

        <div class="text pull-left">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
            <p>$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
            <h6 class="blue">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="image pull-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="images/product.png">
        </div>

        <div class="text pull-left">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
            <p>$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
            <h6 class="blue">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="image pull-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="images/product.png">
        </div>

        <div class="text pull-left">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
            <p>$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
            <h6 class="blue">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML, where items is the container and the item are the elements I need on one line.

```
#shop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

#shop .items {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#shop .item {
    margin: 20px 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

#shop .item .image {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}

#shop .item .image img {
    margin: auto;
}

#shop .item .text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#shop .button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

#shop .cart {
    padding-left: 55px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    float: left;
}

#shop .cart .sep {
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And this the CSS concerning the said elements.

Comment: I think you're missing a `<div id="shop">` from the HTML example code here.

Comment: What exactly do you want, ALL elements on a single line or ALL items <div class="item"> on a single line? The way it is actually written, it's not clear and confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `float` for each item and use `inline-block` :

```
#shop .item {
  margin: 20px 0;
  /*float: left; Remove this*/
  display: inline-block; /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: @AlienArrays in the fiddle doesn't work because you don't have an element with id shop ... http://jsfiddle.net/4d64z/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4d64z/

I got it working close to how you want I think.

I added some `float: left;` to some elements and `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` to some elements

```
#shop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

p {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#shop .items {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#shop .item {
    margin: 20px 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

#shop .item .image {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}
h6 { display: inline; float: left; }

#shop .item .image img {
    margin: auto;
}

#shop .item .text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#shop .button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

#shop .cart {
    padding-left: 55px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    float: left;
}

#shop .cart .sep {
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you mean you want the following 3 tags on the same line;

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
<p>$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
<h6 class="blue">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
```

You can apply your float on these tags directly like so

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor consecteur </p>
<p class="aClass">$79/QUANTITY: 1</p>
<h6 class="blue aClass">Clear <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></h6>
```

And the CSS looks something like this

```
#shop .aClass{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<div>` tags, you might consider using `<span>` tags. They are essentially the same (although there are some other differences), but `<div>` is mainly used for large, block-style divisions, and `<span>` is used for inline elements.